# Set column value as the mean of a group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with columns `X` `Y` `temperature` `Label`

label is an integer between 1 and 9

I want to add an additional column `my_label_mean_temperature` which will contain for each row the mean of the temperatures of the rows that has the same label.

I'm pretty sure i need to start with `my_df.groupby('label')` but not sure how to calculate the mean on temperature and propagate the values on all the rows of my original data frame

Comment: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: Can you please share a piece of your code whatever you have tried

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be solved with the [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) method of pandas.

You could try something like this :

```
df['my_label_mean_temperature'] = df.groupby(['label']).transform('mean')
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'x':np.random.rand(19),
                        'y':np.arange(19),
                        'temp':[22,33,22,55,3,7,55,1,33,4,5,6,7,8,9,4,3,6,2],
                        'label': [1,2,3,4,2,3,9,3,2,9,2,3,9,4,1,2,9,7, 1]})

df['my_label_mean_temperature'] = df.groupby(['label'], sort=False)['temp'].transform('mean')
```

Answer (score 0):

df['my_label_mean_temperature']= df.groupby('label', as_index=False)['temperature'].mean()